# Applying multiple conditions in zf2 left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a `zf2` left join query like this

```
        $select->join(
            'contractor_jobs',
            'contractor_jobs.contractor_id = contractor_info.contractor_id',
            array('job_trade_id'),
            $select::JOIN_LEFT
        );
```

I want to apply another condition as `'contractor_jobs.job_trade_id = $variableName'`  during `joining`. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression:

```
    $join = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('contractor_jobs.contractor_id = contractor_info.contractor_id AND 
                            contractor_jobs.job_trade_id = '.$variableName.' ');

    $select->join(
        'contractor_jobs',
        $join,
        array('job_trade_id'),
        $select::JOIN_LEFT
    );
```

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME DEAR, IT WORKS. THANK YOU :)